# Why does 'ls > ls.out' cause 'ls.out' to be included in list of names?

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect

Why does `$ ls > ls.out` cause 'ls.out' to be included in list of names of files in current directory? Why was this chosen to be? Why not otherwise?

Comment: probably because it first creates a file ls.out and then writes output to it

Comment: If you want to avoid the inclusion you can always store the output file in a different directory.  For example you could choose the parent directory (provided you aren't at the root of the file system) with  `ls > ../ls.out`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When evaluating the command the `>` redirection is resolved first: so by the time `ls` runs the output file has been created already.

This is also the reason why reading and writing to the same file using a `>` redirection within the same command truncates the file; by the time the command runs the file has been truncated already:

```bsh
$ echo foo >bar
$ cat bar
foo
$ <bar cat >bar
$ cat bar
$
```

Tricks to avoid this:

- `<<<"$(ls)" > ls.out` (works for any command that needs to run before the redirection is resolved)

  The command substitution is run before the outer command is evaluated, so `ls` is run before `ls.out` is created:

  ```bsh
  $ ls
  bar  foo
  $ <<<"$(ls)" > ls.out
  $ cat ls.out 
  bar
  foo
  ```

- `ls | sponge ls.out` (works for any command that needs to run before the redirection is resolved)

  `sponge` writes to the file only when the rest of the pipe has finished executing, so `ls` is run before `ls.out` is created (`sponge` is provided with the `moreutils` package):

  ```bsh
  $ ls
  bar  foo
  $ ls | sponge ls.out
  $ cat ls.out 
  bar
  foo
  ```

- `ls * > ls.out` (works for `ls > ls.out`'s specific case)

  The filename expansion is performed before the redirection is resolved, so `ls` will run on its arguments, which won't contain `ls.out`:

  ```bsh
  $ ls
  bar  foo
  $ ls * > ls.out
  $ cat ls.out 
  bar
  foo
  $
  ```

---

On why redirections are resolved before the program / script / whatever is run, I don't see a specific reason why it's *mandatory* to do so, but I see two reasons why it's *better* to do so:

- not redirecting STDIN beforehand would make the program / script / whatever hold until STDIN is redirected;
- not redirecting STDOUT beforehand should necessarily make the shell buffer the program's / script's / whatever's output until STDOUT is redirected;

So a waste of time in the first case and a waste of time and memory in the second case.

This is just what occurs to me, I'm not claiming these are the actual reasons; but I guess that all in all, if one had a choice, they would go with redirecting before anyway for the abovementioned reasons.

Comment: Note that during redirection the shell doesn't actually touch the data (on either input redirection or output redirection). It just opens the file and passes the file descriptor down to the program.

Comment: @PeterGreen That's a helpful note. Suppose there is no file with the name 'out' in the current directory. After running the command 'du -sh * > out', size of the 'out' file won't be printed in the 'out' file's text. This shows that file descriptor of the 'out' file is passed to the command but the file itself has not been saved. Now, running that same command again will lead to size of the 'out' file included in the 'out' file's text. That size is shown to be 0 bytes, indicating that that file has been formatted but still available in the disk(because it existed previously), hence size is 0.

Answer (score 11):

From `man bash`:

> REDIRECTION
>
> Before a command is executed, its input and output  may  be  redirected
>     using  a special notation interpreted by the shell.  Redirection allows
>     commands' file handles to be duplicated, opened, closed, made to  refer
>     to different files, and can change the files the command reads from and
>     writes to.

First sentence, suggests that output is made to go somewhere other than `stdin` with redirection right before the command is executed. Thus, in order to be redirected to file, file must first be created by the shell itself.

To avoid having a file, I suggest you redirect output to named pipe first, and then to file. Note the use of `&` to return control over terminal to the user

```
DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ mkfifo /tmp/namedPipe.fifo                                                                         

DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ls > /tmp/namedPipe.fifo &
[1] 14167

DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ cat /tmp/namedPipe.fifo > ls.out
```

**But why?**

Think about this  - where will be the output ? A program has functions like `printf`, `sprintf` , `puts` , which all by default go to `stdout`, but can their output be gone to file if file doesn't exist in the first place ? It's like water. Can you get a glass of water without putting glass underneath the faucet first ?

Answer (score 10):

I don't disagree with the current answers. The output file has to be opened before the command runs or the command won't have anywhere to write its output.

This is because **"everything is a file"** in our world. Output to screen is SDOUT (aka file descriptor 1). For an application to write to the terminal, it *opens* fd1 and writes to it like a file.

When you redirect an application's output in a shell, you're altering fd1 so it's actually pointing at the file. When you pipe you alter one application's STDOUT to become another's STDIN (fd0).

---

But it's all nice saying that, but you can quite easily look at how this works with `strace`. It's pretty heavy stuff but this example is quite short.

```
strace sh -c "ls > ls.out" 2> strace.out
```

Within `strace.out` we can see the following highlights:

```
open("ls.out", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
```

This opens `ls.out` as `fd3`. Write only. Truncates (overwrites) if exists, otherwise creates.

```
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
close(1)                                = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
```

This is a bit of juggling. We shunt STDOUT (fd1) off to fd10 and close it off. This is because we're not outputting anything to the real STDOUT with this command. It finishes by duplicating the write handle to `ls.out` and closing the original one.

```
stat("/opt/wine-staging/bin/ls", 0x7ffc6bf028c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/oli/bin/ls", 0x7ffc6bf028c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/sbin/ls", 0x7ffc6bf028c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/ls", 0x7ffc6bf028c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/ls", 0x7ffc6bf028c0)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/ls", 0x7ffc6bf028c0)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sbin/ls", 0x7ffc6bf028c0)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/bin/ls", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=110080, ...}) = 0
```

This is it searching for the executable. A lesson perhaps to not have a long path ;)

```
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f0961324a10) = 31933
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 31933
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=31933, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigreturn()                          = 31933
dup2(10, 1)                             = 1
close(10)                               = 0
```

Then the command runs and the parent waits. During this operation any STDOUT will have actually mapped to the open file handle on `ls.out`. When the child issues `SIGCHLD`, this tells the parent process its finished and that it can resume. It finishes off with a little more juggling and a close of `ls.out`.

Why is there *so* much juggling? No I'm not entirely sure either.

---

Of course you can change this behaviour. You could buffer to memory wth something like `sponge` and that'll be invisible from the proceeding command. We're still affecting the file descriptors, but not in a file-system-visible way.

```
ls | sponge ls.out
```

Answer (score 6):

There is also a nice article about [Implementation of redirection and pipe operators in shell](http://www.sarathlakshman.com/2012/09/24/implementation-overview-of-redirection-and-pipe-operators-in-shell/). Which shows how redirection could be implemented so `$ ls > ls.out` could look like:

```c
main(){
    close(1); // Release fd no - 1
    open("ls.out", "w"); // Open a file with fd no = 1
    // Child process
    if (fork() == 0) {
        exec("ls"); 
    }
}
```