# In what order does the shell execute commands and stream redirection?

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect

I was trying to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to a file today, and I came across this:

```
<command> > file.txt 2>&1
```

This apparently redirects `stderr` to `stdout` first, and then the resulting `stdout` is redirected to `file.txt`.

However, why isn't the order `<command> 2>&1 > file.txt`? One would naturally read this as (assuming execution from left to right) the command being executed first, the `stderr` being redirected to `stdout` and then, the resulting `stdout` being written to `file.txt`. But the above only redirects `stderr` to the screen.

How does the shell interpret both the commands?

Comment: TLCL says this "First we redirect standard output to the
file, and then we redirect file descriptor 2 (standard error) to file descriptor one (standard output)" and "Notice that the order of the redirections is significant. The redirection of standard error must always occur after redirecting standard output or it doesn't work"

Comment: @Zanna: Yes, my question precisely came from reading that in TLCL! :) I'm interested in knowing why it wouldn't work, i.e., how the shell interprets commands in general.

Comment: Well, in your question you say the opposite "This apparently redirects stderr to stdout first..." - what I understand from TLCL, is that the shell sends stdout to the file and **then** stderr to stdout (ie to the file). My interpretation is that if you send stderr to stdout, then it will be displayed in the terminal, and subsequent redirection of stdout will not include stderr (ie the redirection of stderr to the screen completes before the redirection of stdout happens?)

Comment: I know this is an old-fashioned thing to say, but *your shell comes with a manual that explains these things* - e.g. [redirection in the `bash` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections-1). By the way, redirections are not commands.

Comment: The command *can't* be executed before the redirections are set up: When the `execv`-family syscall is invoked to actually hand the subprocess off to the command being started, the shell is then out of the loop (no longer has code executing in that process) and has no possible way to control what happens from that point on; redirections thus *must all* be performed before execution begins, while the shell has a copy of itself running in the process it `fork()`ed to run your command in.

Comment: Incidentally, there is a shortcut, `&>`, available in Bash. `&>file` is equivalent to `>file 2>&1`, and so `command &>file` will redirect both `&1` and `&2` to `file`.

Answer (score 43):

When you run `<command> 2>&1 > file.txt` stderr is redirected by `2>&1` to where stdout currently goes, your terminal. After that, stdout is redirected to the file by `>`, but stderr is not redirected with it, so stays as terminal output.

With `<command> > file.txt 2>&1` stdout is first redirected to the file by `>`, then `2>&1` redirects stderr to where stdout is going, which is the file.

It may seem counter intuitive to start with, but when you think of the redirections in this way, and remember that they are processed from left to right it makes much more sense.

Comment: It makes sense if you think in terms of file-descriptors and "dup/fdreopen" calls being executed in order from left-to-right

Answer (score 20):

It might make sense if you trace it out.

In the beginning, stderr and stdout go to the same thing (usually the terminal, which I call here `pts`):

```
fd/0 -> pts
fd/1 -> pts
fd/2 -> pts
```

I'm referring to stdin, stdout and stderr by their *file descriptor* numbers here: they are file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

Now, in the first set of redirections, we have `> file.txt` and `2>&1`.

So:

1. `> file.txt`: `fd/1` now goes to `file.txt`. With `>`, `1` is the implied file descriptor when nothing is specified, so this is `1>file.txt`:

   ```
   fd/0 -> pts
   fd/1 -> file.txt
   fd/2 -> pts
   ```
2. `2>&1`: `fd/2` now goes to wherever `fd/1` *currently* goes:

   ```
   fd/0 -> pts
   fd/1 -> file.txt
   fd/2 -> file.txt
   ```

On the other hand, with `2>&1 > file.txt`, the order being reversed:

1. `2>&1`: `fd/2` now goes to wherever `fd/1` currently goes, which means nothing changes:

   ```
   fd/0 -> pts
   fd/1 -> pts
   fd/2 -> pts
   ```
2. `> file.txt`: `fd/1` now goes to `file.txt`:

   ```
   fd/0 -> pts
   fd/1 -> file.txt
   fd/2 -> pts
   ```

The important point is that redirection does not mean that the redirected file descriptor will follow all future changes to the target file descriptor; it will only take on the *current* state.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a more natural explanation! :) You made a slight typo though in `2.` of the second part; `fd/1 -> file.txt` and not `fd/2 -> file.txt`.

Answer (score 11):

I think it helps to think that the shell will set up the redirection on the left first, and *complete* it before setting up the next redirection.

[*The Linux Command Line*](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php/) by William Shotts says

> First we redirect standard output to the file, and then we redirect
>   file descriptor 2 (standard error) to file descriptor one (standard
>   output)

this makes sense, but then

> Notice that the order of the redirections is significant. The
>   redirection of standard error must always occur after redirecting
>   standard output or it doesn't work

but actually, we can redirect stdout to stderr after redirecting stderr to a file with the same effect

```
$ uname -r 2>/dev/null 1>&2
$
```

So, in `command > file 2>&1`, the shell sends stdout to a file, then sends stderr to stdout (which is being sent to a file). Whereas, in `command 2>&1 > file` the shell first redirects stderr to stdout (ie displays it in the terminal where stdout normally goes) and then afterwards, redirects stdout to the file. TLCL is misleading in saying that we must redirect stdout first: since we can redirect stderr to a file first and then send stdout to it. What we cannot do, is redirect stdout to stderr or vice versa *before* redirection to a file. Another example

```
$ strace uname -r 1>&2 2> /dev/null 
4.8.0-30-generic
```

We might think this would dispose of stdout to the same place as stderr, but it doesn't, it redirects stdout to stderr (the screen) first, and then only redirects stderr, as when we tried it the other way round...

I hope this brings a little bit of light...

Comment: So much more eloquent!

Comment: Ah, now I understand! Thank you so much, @Zanna and @Arronical! Just starting out on my command line journey. :)

Comment: @TrainHeartnet it's a pleasure! Hope you are enjoying it as much as me :D

Comment: @Zanna: Indeed, I am! :D

Comment: @TrainHeartnet no worries, a world of frustration and joy awaits you!

Answer (score 10):

You got a few very good answers already. Let me stress though that there are two different concepts involved here, the understanding of which helps tremendously:

## Background: File descriptor vs. file table

Your file descriptor is just a number 0...n, which is the index in the file descriptor table in your process. By convention, STDIN=0, STDOUT=1, STDERR=2 (note that the terms `STDIN` etc. here are just symbols/macros used by convention in some programming languages and man pages, there is not an actual "object" called STDIN; for the purpose of this discussion, STDIN *is* 0, etc.).

That file descriptor table in itself does not contain any information whatsoever about what the actual file is. Instead, it contains a pointer to a different file table; the latter contains information about an actual physical file (or block device, or pipe, or whatever else Linux can address via the file mechanism) and more information (i.e., whether it's for reading or writing).

So when you use `>` or `<` in your shell, you simply replace the pointer of the respective file descriptor to point to something else. The syntax `2>&1` simply points descriptor 2 to wherever 1 points. `> file.txt` simply opens `file.txt` for writing and lets STDOUT (file decsriptor 1) point to that.

There are other goodies, e.g. `2>(xxx)`  (i.e.: create a new process running `xxx`, create a pipe, connect file descriptor 0 of the new process to the reading end of the pipe and connect the file descriptor 2 of the original process to the writing end of the pipe).

This is also the basis for "file handle magic" in other software than your shell. For example, you could, in your Perl script, `dup`licate the STDOUT file descriptor into another (temporary) one, then re-open STDOUT to a newly created temporary file. From this point on, all STDOUT output from your own Perl script *and all `system()` calls* of that script will end up in that temporary file. When done, you can re-`dup` your STDOUT to the temporary descriptor you saved it to, and presto, all is as before. You can even write to that temporary descriptor meanwhile, so while your actual STDOUT output goes to the temporary file, you can still actually output stuff to the *real* STDOUT (commonly, the user).

## Answer

To apply the background information given above to your question:

> In what order does the shell execute commands and stream redirection?

Left to right.

> `<command> > file.txt 2>&1`

1. `fork` off a new process.
2. Open `file.txt` and store its pointer in the file descriptor 1 (STDOUT).
3. Point STDERR (file descriptor 2) to whatever the fd 1 points to right now (which again is the already opened `file.txt` of course).
4. `exec` the `<command>`

> This apparently redirects stderr to stdout first, and then the resulting stdout is redirected to file.txt.

This would make sense if there were only *one* table, but as explained above there are two. File descriptors are not pointing to each other recursively, it makes no sense to think "redirect STDERR to STDOUT". The correct thought is "point STDERR to wherever STDOUT points". If you change STDOUT later, STDERR stays where it is, it does not magically go along with further changes to STDOUT.

Comment: Upvoting for the "file handle magic" bit - although it doesn't directly answer the question I learnt something new today...

Answer (score 3):

The order is left to right. Bash's manual has already covered what you ask. Quote from `REDIRECTION` section of the manual:

```
   Redirections  are  processed  in  the
   order they appear, from left to right.
```

and a few lines later:

```
   Note that the order of redirections is signifi‐
   cant.  For example, the command

          ls > dirlist 2>&1

   directs both standard output and standard error
   to the file dirlist, while the command

          ls 2>&1 > dirlist

   directs   only  the  standard  output  to  file
   dirlist, because the standard error was  dupli‐
   cated from the standard output before the stan‐
   dard output was redirected to dirlist.
```

It is important to note that redirection is resolved first before any commands run ! See https://askubuntu.com/a/728386/295286

Answer (score 3):

It's always left to right... except when

Just like in Math we do left to right except multiplication and division is done before addition and subtraction, except operations inside parenthesis (+ -) would be done before multiplication and division.

As per the Bash beginners guide here ([Bash Beginners Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html)) there are 8 orders of hierarchy of what comes first (before left to right):

1. Brace expansion "{}"
2. Tilde expansion "~"
3. Shell parameter and variable expression "$"
4. Command substitution "$(command)"
5. Arithmetic expression "$((EXPRESSION))"
6. Process Substitution *what we are talking about here* "<(LIST)" or ">(LIST)"
7. Word Splitting "'< space>< tab>< newline>'"
8. File Name Expansion "*", "?", etc.

So it's always left to right... except when...

Comment: To be clear: process substitution and redirection are two independent operations. You can do one without the other.  Having process substitution does not mean that bash decides to change the order in which it processes redirection