# How to setup cron job

Tags: 22.04, php, cron, php7

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and have `php-fpm`, so I am using `php8.2` and `php7.3`.

I use 7.3 for Interspire Email Marketer, (IEM).
In IEM, it found the cron path to be: `/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/mail.domain.com/admin/cron/cron.php`

The problem is, is that the PHP url: `/usr/bin/php` links to `php8.2`.

IEM uses `php7.3`, and based on tests so far changing the PHP path to: `/usr/bin/php7.3` doesn't seem to be working. I have set the cron job to run every five minutes by using the full path:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/mail.domain.com/admin/cron/cron.php
```

But like I say, it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas how to begin troubleshooting it and where to look... or how to get it working?

Comment: You can send cron job errors to a log file. Put this in your crontab - `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/mail.domain.com/admin/cron/cron.php 2>&1 >> /home/username/cronoutput.txt`

Comment: thanks @stumblebee. I'll give that a go. How do I get it to use php7.3? instead of the default 8.2?

Comment: I actually tried it and it output the file with the following content: An internal error occured. Please contact your administrator and describe the steps you took before you encounter this error message.</p><p>Error msg: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_gpc()

And as far as I know thats because magic_quotes was deprecated at php7.4. And the default php being used in the cron is 8.2.

7.3 would have magic_quotes as far as I know?

Comment: When I try: */5 * * * * /usr/bin/php7.3 -f /var/www/mail.domain.com/admin/cron/cron.php 2>&1 >> /home/username/cronoutput.txt the created text file is empty.

Comment: If the intent is to capture both stdout and stderr to the file, you'll need to swap the order of redirections i.e. `... >> /home/username/cronoutput.txt 2>&1`. See for example [In what order does the shell execute commands and stream redirection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860147/in-what-order-does-the-shell-execute-commands-and-stream-redirection)

Comment: thanks @steeldriver I just woke upo and tried it and its now working. But thanks. I will try that though.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, my bad.

Comment: @steeldriver . Thanks guys, I got it working after your input so thanks. Much appreciated

Comment: @stumblebee. Thanks guys, I got it working after your input so thanks. Much appreciated